# Error when use android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm new android dev. I have tried to work with

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ducbo.flynow_ver20.payment_section">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/payment_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_header">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/payment_btn_back"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnback" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/payment_btn_back"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/thanh_toan"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="28sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/payment_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/payment_header">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/payment_types"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/payment_types_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/payment_tab_method"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/payment_types">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/toolbar"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"-->

                    <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"-->
                    <!--app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />-->
                    <!--android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"-->

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="fixed" />
                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/payment_table_passenger"
            layout="@layout/table_passenger"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/payment_types_container"></include>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/payment_startdp"
            layout="@layout/fm_booking_startdp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/payment_table_passenger"></include>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/payment_enddp"
            layout="@layout/fragment_booking_enddp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/payment_startdp">
        </include>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/payment_btn_submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/payment_enddp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_orange"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

With each tab, I used one fragment to show tab's content. After that, I included some layout below Coordinator but it wasn't appear below Coordinator. When I checked again in Design tab on Android studio, I realized that the height of coordinator seemingly unlimited even though I set wrap_content for it. I think that is problem and I have changed height attribute of Coordinator to specific number and my input layout appeared but I don't want like this. What can I fix the height of Coordinator to wrap content?